# Differential Forms and Gauge Invariance?

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In the Sean Carroll book on GR, page 86 in chapter 2 says
$$d(A+d\lambda)=F,$$
where $A$ is vector potential and $\lambda$ is some $0$-form scalar. $F$ is the electromagnetic field strength tensor.

I understand how $dA=F$, but I don't understand why adding specifically a $0$-form is allowed, but not a $1$-form. As far as I understand (which could be wrong), the exterior derivative is linear, so $d(A+B)=dA+dB$, and if we have $A$ be vector potential and $B=dC$, for $C$ as a $k$-form, We will have $dA+d(dC)=dA=F$.

What is my misunderstanding and why must we use a $0$-form?

Answer (score 10):

The exterior derivative of a $k$-form is a $k+1$-form. The square of the exterior derivative is zero, so if you add an exact one-form to $A$, that is $B= d\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is a zero-form, you will still have $d(A+B) = dA + d^2 \lambda=dA=F$.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is simply that the sum $A+d\lambda$ should still be a $1$-form, just like the original $A$ itself.  Why this has to be a case is clearer if we express the quantities in terms of spacetime indices, so that
$$\nabla^{\mu}\left(A^{\nu}+\nabla^{\nu}\lambda\right)-(\mu\leftrightarrow\nu)=F^{\mu\nu}.$$
(The awkwardness of the indices and the difference on the left-hand side are why the notation with forms can be so much more convenient, but it is necessary to understand what the forms mean in terms of components to really grasp what they represent.)  If $\lambda$ were not a $0$-form—that is, a scalar function of spacetime—the quantity being differentiated on the left would not have coherent indices.  What, after all, is the meaning of $A^{\nu}+(\nabla^{\nu}\Lambda^{\rho}-\nabla^{\rho}\Lambda^{\nu})$?  The two terms have different collections of indices; the $1$-form $A$ has four components, while the $2$-form $d\Lambda$ has sixteen (ten of which, however, are zero due to antisymmetry).  There is no straightforward way to add these together.

[It *is* possibly to define, formally, a sum of differential forms of different types—and this can occasionally even be useful as an intermediate step in certain kinds of calculations, such as the construction of spinors over curved spacetime manifolds.  However, this requires a great deal of care, and sums of forms of inhomogeneous degrees are never direct physical observables.  They only appear contracted together in such a way as to make the inhomogeneity disappear (for example, in the abstract spinor case, in appropriately chosen bilinears of the form $\bar{\Psi}\mathcal{O}\Psi$).]

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$First of all, the space of $k$-forms is a vector space. Hence the sum of two $k$-forms is a $k$-form. In contrast, the sum of a $k$-form and an $\ell$-form *is not a form of fixed degree*<sup>1</sup>. So if $A$ is a one-form you can add to it a one-form.

Now, you have defined the curvature, $F_A$, as $F_A:=\d A$. So you are looking for a one-form, $B$, such that adding it to $A$ the curvature doesn't change:
$$\d(A+B)=:F_{A+B}\overset{!}{=}F_A :=\d A.\tag{1}$$
As you have observed, the exterior derivative is linear, so (1) becomes
$$\d B \overset{!}{=} 0.$$
I.e. $B$ must be a closed form. Now, if you are working on a space with simple topology, such as $\mathbb{R}^d$, or if you are working locally, on a patch of a space, you can invoke [Poincaré's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_lemma). This tells you that, in those cases, the closed one-form $B$ is exact! I.e. you can find a *zero-form* $\lambda$, such that $B=\d \lambda$, from which (1) takes the form that is stated in your book.

More generally, when you want to consider spaces with interesting topology you should invoke [Hodge decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory#Operators_in_Hodge_theory). (A variant of) this, asserts that any closed $k$-form, can be written as a [harmonic $k$-form](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Harmonic_form) plus an exact $k$-form, i.e. the exterior derivative of a $(k-1)$-form. Here
$$B = B_\text{harm} + \d \lambda,$$
with $\lambda$ a *zero-form*. The harmonic piece, $B_\text{harm}$ exists only in spaces with interesting topology, since the space of harmonic $k$-forms is isomorphic to the $k$-th [cohomology group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomology). In these cases, the equation of your book is indeed not the most general case, and you can shift $A$ by a harmonic one-form without altering the curvature. Physically such shifts correspond to large-gauge transformations, in the sense that they are not continuously connected to the identity.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>you can still define this in the vector space $\Omega^\bullet :=\bigoplus_k \Omega^k$, but that's not what you should be doing here.</sup>